# What is the Keyboard Application Shortcut to set a key to mute volume in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio

I have Xubuntu 16.04 on my Chromebook using Crouton.  I am trying to enable my multimedia keys to work. I was able to get the volume up and down keys working 
respectively with:

'pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%'

'pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%'

What is the command to mute volume?

Comment: I think it is set-sink-mute 0 1 to mute and set-sink-mute 0 0 to un mute, from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 1
```

Unmute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
```

Comment: I actually got it with this.  As this will bind a single key to mute/unmute which is what I needed.:

pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle